# match .get() for None: how to avoid useless borrow?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

How can I mutate a `hash_map` in the `None` clause of `match hash_map.get(...)` (and similarly for `vec.get`)?

```
match hash_map.get(...) {
    None => {
        // How can I mutate hash_map here?
    }
}
```

As a full example, the following does not compile:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn map_question(map: &mut HashMap<String, String>) {
    match map.get(&"foo".to_string()) {
        Some(s) => {
            // Do something with s
        },
        None => {
            // I'd like to mutate `map` here, but I'm getting "cannot borrow map"
            map.insert("bar".to_string(), "x".to_string());
        }
    }
}
```

The reason is that the `Option<&String>` returned by [`map.get()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) is still in scope, so `map` is borrowed. Here's the full error message:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*map` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> test.rs:10:13
   |
4  |     match map.get(&"foo".to_string()) {
   |           --- immutable borrow occurs here
...
10 |             map.insert("bar".to_string(), "x".to_string());
   |             ^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
11 |         }
12 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

**My solution** has been to work around this problem by using `if let`:

```
fn map_alternative(map: &mut HashMap<String, String>) {
    if let Some(s) = map.get(&"foo".to_string()) {
        // Do something with s
    }
    // Now we can mutate `map` because the `Option` return by `.get`
    // is out of scope.
    map.insert("bar".to_string(), "x".to_string());
}
```

(Note that we're not using an `else` clause here, because the `Option<&String>` returned by `.get` would still be in scope in the `else` clause for some reason.)

But this seems somewhat unsatisfactory. Can I tell Rust that when I'm matching `None`, I'm done with the `Option` object I got from `.get`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/30243606/155423; where that OP discovered the same problem with `if let {} else {}`.

Comment: The related questions appears to have some relevant suggestions as well. Here's one [specifically about vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42260092/155423)